# 3D Curve Geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an array of Vector3s that define an arbitrary curved shape in 3D space.  I can render an outline of the curve in Three.js by using a `THREE.Geometry` and a `THREE.Line`, but I'd like to fill it with color.

I tried using `THREE.ShapeGeometry` and `THREE.Mesh`, but it seems as though `THREE.ShapeGeometry` is for 2D planes only (the z-coordinates of my vertices are being ignored).  I also tried to use `THREE.Geometry` and define the faces in addition to the vertices I wanted, but had no luck.

How should I go about doing this?

Code:

```
geom.vertices = curve.getPoints(100);

for (var i = 0; i < 97; i++) {
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i, i + 1, i + 2));
}

var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

obj = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
scene.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by changing the code in the question above to the excerpt below:

```
geom.vertices = curve.getPoints(100);

for (var i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, i + 1, i + 2));
}

var materialObj = { color : 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide };
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(materialObj);

obj = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
scene.add(obj);
```